# Finding the fastest section of a waypoint track

Tags: algorithm, gps

Sports tracker applications usually record a timestamp and a location in regular intervals in order to store the entire track. Analytical applications then allow to find certain statistics, such as the track subsection with the highest speed of a fixed duration (e.g. time needed for 5 miles). Or vice versa, the longest distance traversed in certain time span (e.g. Cooper distance in 12 minutes).

I'm wondering what's the most elegant and/or efficient approach to compute such sections.

In a naive approach, I'd normalize and interpolate the waypoints to get a more fine grained list of waypoints, either with a fixed time interval or fix distance steps. Then, move a sliding window representing my time span resp. distance segement over the list and search for the best sub-list matching my criteria. Is there any better way?

Comment: You may want to consider posting this to gis.stackexchange.com instead, for better results.

Comment: This seems to be very much a coding question, @DavidPfeffer. The mere presence of geographic information shouldn't condemn something to the GIS list.

Answer (score 1):

Elegance and efficiency are in the eye of the beholder.

Personally, I think your interpolation idea is elegant.

I imagine the interpolation algorithm is easy to build and the search you'll perform on the subsequent data is easy to perform. This can lead to tight code whose correctness can be easily verified. Furthermore, the interpolation algorithms probably already exist and are multi-purpose, so you don't have to to repeat yourself (DRY). Your suggested solution has the benefit of separating data *processing* from data *analysis*. Modularity of this nature is often considered a component of elegance.

Efficiency - are we talking about speed, space, or lines of code? You could try to combine the interpolation step with the search step to save space, but this will probably sacrifice speed and code simplicity. Certainly speed is sacrificed in the sense that multiple queries cannot take advantage of previous calculations.

When you consider the efficiency of your code, worry not so much about how the computer will handle it, or how you will code it. Think more deeply about the intrinsic time complexity of your approach. I suspect both the interpolation and search can be made to take place in O(N) time, in which case it would take vast amounts of data to bog you down: it is difficult to make an O(N) algorithm perform very badly.

In support of the above, interpolation is just estimating intermediate points between two values, so this is linear in the number of values and linear in the number of intermediate points. Searching could probably be done with a numerical variant of the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), which is also linear.